# Change boolean in the array of objects

Tags: javascript

I have radio buttons and i need change selected radio button to true and other to false

```
changeHandler (index, event) {
    this.array[index].checked = true;
}
```

I have the following array structure:

```
[
 {checked: false, title: 'first'},
 {checked: false, title: 'second'},
 {checked: false, title: 'third'}
]
```

When i select radio "first" i need to change this obj value to true, and others to false, and so on.

Comment: Can you include your HTML and javascript?

Comment: Please show us your full code along with html. We will not be able to fully understand what exactly you are looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set all `checked` members to false but the one having the selected index :

```
changeHandler (index, event) {
    this.array.forEach((elem, idx) => elem.checked = idx == index);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could find all your inputs by the title and add an event listener.

Here's my implementation:

```js
// after document load

const myRadioButtons = [
 {checked: false, title: 'first'},
 {checked: false, title: 'second'},
 {checked: false, title: 'third'}
];

myRadioButtons.forEach(radio => {
  function updateRadioValue(id, value) {
    document.querySelector(`#${id}`).checked = value;
    myRadioButtons.find(item => item.title === id).checked = value;
  }
  
  function checkRadioAndResetOthers() {
    myRadioButtons
      .filter(item => item.title !== radio.title)
      .forEach(item => updateRadioValue(item.title, false));
  
    radio.checked = true;
    console.log(myRadioButtons);
  }

  document
    .querySelector(`#${radio.title}`)
    .addEventListener('change', checkRadioAndResetOthers);
})
```

```html
<input type="radio" id="first"/> First
<input type="radio" id="second"/> Second
<input type="radio" id="third"/> Third
```

Answer (score 0):

See [`Array.prototype.forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach).

```js
const array = [
 {checked: false, title: 'first'},
 {checked: false, title: 'second'},
 {checked: false, title: 'third'}
];

function changeHandler(index) {
  array.forEach((item, i) => item.checked = index === i);
}

changeHandler(0)
console.log(array);

changeHandler(1)
console.log(array);

changeHandler(2)
console.log(array);
```